# RPi pulls files from Windows computer

Tags: tftp

I have a dropbox uploader script that can upload files to my dropbox account, and I want to create a program where my Windows computer will send files to my RPi, which will then hand them over to my dropbox account. As far as I know, FTP is the best way to do this, but it seems I need to know the IP address of my Pi, which changes (obviously). Is there a simple way to send files from a Windows computer to a RPi?

Comment: *"..it seems I need to know the IP address of my Pi.."* You need the IP address no matter how you do this.  If this is within a LAN, just assign the pi a fixed address with the router.  If it's from outside, you're sort of out of luck unless you buy a domain name and use a dynamic DNS service, I think.

Answer (score 1):

FTP and SCP are both programs that will allow you to send/receive files.

---

If your problem is with your raspberry pi's IP changing, you can try a few different things:

- If your pi is on a remote network, which connects to the internet and gets a new ip address, you can look into **dynamic dns** and the providers and tools that will help you get your desired results.
- If your pi is on your LAN, you can give it a static ip via the router, or have the [pi itself use a static ip](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/setting-a-static-eth0-ip).
- If you don't want to do that, or don't have admin access to your LAN, you could look into **multicasting** or **broadcasting** onto your LAN.